# how to check if J.W.T token in local storage is legit?

Tags: jwt, local-storage

I am using local storage for my website to keep user logged in.
On loading of page i'm checking if there exists a token in local storage, however, before login if i put a random value in local storage with key "auth-token" then after refreshing, the page will act in a state where user has logged in.
how may i check if the token is legit and not some random value, before loading of page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use your JWT to call a service it will return unauthorized access so therefore you can logout the user. That’s how you can know if it’s a valid token.